# Keep updating error message when validating multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a form that I am validating server side and adding style (red border) to make clear which fields are invalid using jQuery. At the bottom there also is a message which indicates why it is invalid.

The borders work fine, but the problem is the message at the bottom. When for example some fields are invalid and I fix them, the last error message is still always displayed.

This is because an if statement in the following code:

```
$("body").on("blur","input",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    accountform = $(".account-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
     type:'post',
     url:"includes/updateaccount.php",
     data:({accountform: accountform}),
     success:function(data){
         var obj = JSON.parse(data);

         for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
             var status = obj[i].status;
             var field = obj[i].field;
             if(status == 'error'){
                 var message = obj[i].message;
                    $( "#updateresult" ).show().empty().append( message );
                    $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' ).addClass('invalid-input');
             }else if(status == 'success'){
                 $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' ).removeClass('invalid-input');
             }
         }
     }
 });
});
```

This code:

```
if(status == 'error'){
    var message = obj[i].message;
    $( "#updateresult" ).show().empty().append( message );
    $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' ).addClass('invalid-input');
}else if(status == 'success'){
    $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' ).removeClass('invalid-input');
}
```

Does not remove the message when all is okay. This is because if one input field has status `success` there will be no error message at all.

I tried this :

```
if(status == 'error'){
    var message = obj[i].message;
    $( "#updateresult" ).show().empty().append( message );
    $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' ).addClass('invalid-input');
}else if(status == 'success'){
    $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' ).removeClass('invalid-input');
    $( "#updateresult" ).hide();
}
```

But like I said, this removes the error message because it never reaches the `error` status if one input field has status `success`.

This is an example of the JSON I am receiving:

```
[ 
    { 
    "status":"error",
    "field":"voornaam",
    "message":"Vul een voornaam in"
    },
    { 
    "status":"success",
    "field":"achternaam"
    },
    { 
    "status":"error",
    "field":"telefoon",
    "message":"Vul een telefoonnummer in"
    },
    { 
    "status":"success",
    "field":"email"
    },
    { 
    "status":"success",
    "field":"huisnummer"
    },
    { 
    "status":"success",
    "field":"postcode"
    },
    { 
    "status":"success",
    "field":"straat"
    },
    { 
    "status":"success",
    "field":"woonplaats"
    }
]
```

Comment: You need to check if [`any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of the results has `status: "error"`. If it is, show the message, otherwise, hide it.

Comment: @MoshFeu Thanks, but I get error messages when trying an if statement like this: `if(obj.some(status) == 'error')` or `if(obj.some("error"))`. I get `Uncaught TypeError: error is not a function`.

Comment: Because this is not they way you should use `some` :)

Comment: Do you manage to use `some`?

Comment: @MoshFeu Not really lol. I've tried a few things but not with the result I need.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? Please, update the code in the question..

Comment: @MoshFeu I solved it in another way, instead of displaying messages at the bottom, I just show them under each input in the loop.

Comment: That's a nice product. I would suggest you to solve the previous approach, just for the sport :)

Comment: @MoshFeu Yeah I will, it might come in handy in the future.